# How to disable double click on advanced datagrid grouping title?

Tags: apache-flex, grouping, advanceddatagrid, double-click, selectable

I have an advanced datagrid that has a grouping on it. With the items inside of the grouping I have it setup where you double click on an item and it will create a popup that allows the user to edit that entry. The problem that I am having is that I can double click on the group title and the popup is activated with blank information. How do I prevent this from working?

Here is the mxml code

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="plugList" designViewDataType="tree" width="100%" height="100%" 
         initialize="gc.refresh();" doubleClickEnabled="true" itemDoubleClick="plugList_itemDoubleClickHandler(event)">
        <mx:dataProvider>
            <mx:GroupingCollection2 id="gc" source="{plugs}">
                <mx:grouping>
                    <mx:Grouping>
                        <mx:GroupingField name="traderTitle"/>
                    </mx:Grouping>
                </mx:grouping>
            </mx:GroupingCollection2>
        </mx:dataProvider>
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Title" dataField="traderTitle"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Anchor" dataField="traderAnchor"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="URL" dataField="url"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="status" headerText="Status" width="75"/>
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `event target` is not the single row but the entire datagrid component, you cannot use this object.
If the selectionMode property is set to `singleRow` (which is the default), you can use the `selectedItem` property to point the target row.
 Then  you can check for the presence of the children property to distinguish between a father node and a simple leaf.

This is a simple doubleClick listener function example:

```
protected function plugList_itemDoubleClickHandler(event:ListEvent):void
{
    if(((Object)(event.target.selectedItem)).hasOwnProperty('children')){
        trace('not a leaf');
    }else{
        Alert.show("Selected  "+event.target.selectedItem.desc);
    }   
}
```

Davide

Answer (score 0):

That would be handled in the plugList_itemDoubleClickHandler function. Have a conditional statement to and look at the event.target, not sure of the syntax for it off hand, but in debug mode you should be able to see a difference between the item and header that you can watch for. If its a header, dont show the popup